# How do I populate .net datasets from multiple tables using vb.net from oracle 11g

Tags: sql, vb.net, oracle11g

I have an Oracle 11g database that contains 13 tables or so with varying amount of columns.

I know how to retrieve information from one table at a time, but I need to retrieve a varying number of columns from multiple tables and populate a DataSet.

I'm new to SQL and database programming, so detailed responses would be greatly appreciated.

Each table contains a time column.

For example:

```
select col2, col4, col5,col10 
from table1 
where TimeCol >= IntialTime and TimeCol <= FinalTime 
order by TimeCol desc;
```

What I'm looking for is a single query that will retrieve multiple tables with the format above.

Just to clarify what I'm looking for.
Say I have 5 tables.
Tbl1, Tbl2, Tbl3, Tbl4, Tbl5

Each containing a Time Column and say 10 additional columns.
Tbl1 contains; Time, ColA, ColB, ColC...ColJ
Tbl2 contains; Time, ColK, ColL, ColM...ColT
Tbl3 contains; Time, ColU, ColV, ColW...ColAD
Tbl4 ...
Tbl5 ...

How do I write a select statement that will retrieve Tbl1 Time, ColA, ColC, ColD along with Tbl2 ColL, ColM, ColN, ColP along with Tbl3 ColU, ColW, ColAA, ColAC etc. based on a time range.

Answer (score 0):

You can just nest the queries...

```
SELECT cols FROM table....
SELECT cols FROM table2....
SELECT cols FROM table3....
```

The `DataSet` will hold a collection of `DataTables`, so `Datatable[0]` will hold the first query etc..

```
DataSet ds = new DataSet();
//populate dataset...
DataTable firstQuery = ds.Tables[0];

OracleCommand oraCommand = new OracleCommand("SELECT cols FROM table....; 
                                     SELECT cols FROM table2....", dbconnection);
```

Comment: Being new to SQL, how do I nest the queries?

Comment: is this inline SQL or are you using a stored procedure?

Comment: Inline. At this point in time, using a stored procedure would be a little over my head.

Comment: Do you just need `SELECT * FROM...; SELECT * FROM...;` etc

Comment: Would I just add each select statement to the OracleCommand.Parameters.Add method? Then create an OracleDataAdapter, DataSet and use the fill method to populate the Dataset?

Answer (score 0):

With [Oracle SQL Developer](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/issue-archive/2012/12-jan/o12sql-1408573.html), you can easily test your statements. That's a great tool. The [Oracle doc](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28286/statements_10002.htm#SQLRF01702) provides everything you are going to need. The [Oracle samples](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/indexes/samplecode/dotnet-sample-522126.html) can be a begin for you.

Your question is a little bit unclear.
If you wanna create a [view](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28286/statements_8004.htm#SQLRF01504), then Oracle provides documentation in addition. hth for your start

Comment: What I'm looking for is a single query that will allow me to retrieve multiple(not all and not the same every time) columns from 2 or more tables based on the time column.  Thank you for your response. BTW, I've been using SQL Developer to view my tables and execute single queries.  What I've been doing to this point is executing a single query, then saving it to a CSV file, then merging all the results with Excel.

Comment: @user3083002 aha .. maybe it would be an option for you to use your programming language (in your case, vb.net) to build sql queries which are depending on the given dates  ("...   based on a time range ").

Answer (score 0):

`Join` will solve the problem .I hope..

```
SELECT  col2, col4, col5,col10 
FROM table1 
INNER JOIN table2 on table2.time column= table1.time column
WHERE TimeCol >= IntialTime and TimeCol <= FinalTime
```

Comment: So, the above will join Table1 and 2 and the rows will be in sync. Does it also take col2,4,5,10 from Table 2? To get 3 or more tables, do I just add additional "inner join"? What if I need different columns from each table?

Comment: I attempted to run your script replacing the columns and table names with what I have. I get the following error:  SQL Error: ORA-00918: column ambiguously defined
00918. 00000 -  "column ambiguously defined"

Comment: To get more tables in the select just add `Select table1.colname,table2.colname fROM table1,table2 wHERE TABLE1.COLNAME=table2.colname `